# React hook component renders before API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create a React app which let's you list pokemons and types.
I fetch data from the PokeAPI. Is it a good practice to fetch it from the App component and then pass it to the child components, or is it better to fetch them from the child?

I am fetching it in the main app, I can see the fetch works because I console.log the data, but my component doesn't get it, and because of that I get a props.map is not a function in .

Here is my App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PokemonList from "./components/PokemonList";

const App = (props) => {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);

  const [types, setTypes] = useState([]);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const getPokemons = () => {
    const axios = require("axios").default;
    axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then(function (response) {
      console.log("Fetched pokemons");
      console.log(response.data.results);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setPokemons(response.data.results);
    });
  };

  const getTypes = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const axios = require("axios").default;
    axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type").then(function (response) {
      console.log("Fetched types");
      console.log(response.data.results);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setTypes(response.data.results);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/pokemons" onClick={getPokemons}>
                Pokemons
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/types">Types</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/pokemons">
            <Pokemons pokemons={pokemons} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/types">
            <Types />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

function Pokemons(pokemons) {
  return <PokemonList props={pokemons} />;
}

function Types(typeList) {
  return <h2>TYPES:</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

Here is my PokemonList.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "semantic-ui-react";
import PokeCard from "./PokeCard";

const Pokemonlist = (props) => {
  let content = (
    <Card.Group>
      {props.map(function (object, i) {
        return <PokeCard pokemon={object} key={i} />;
      })}
    </Card.Group>
  );

  return content;
};

export default Pokemonlist;
```

and last here is my PokeCard.js

```
import { Card, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import React from "react";

const PokeCard = (pokemon) => {
  let content = (
    <Card>
      <Card.Content>
        <Image floated="right" size="mini" src={pokemon.img} />
        <Card.Header>{pokemon.name}</Card.Header>
        <Card.Meta>{pokemon.base_experience}</Card.Meta>
        <Card.Description>ID: {pokemon.id}</Card.Description>
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  );

  return content;
};

export default PokeCard;
```

So the basic idea is:

On the main page you click Pokemons button, which calls the fetch then renders the PokemonList component which basically just renders multiple PokeCard components from the data I fetched.

1, What am I missing here?

2, In my situation when nothing changes do I need to use useEffect?

3, When should I fetch the data, and where?

EDIT: I want to use hooks with zero classes

Comment: In your **PokemonList.js** you have run map function on `props`. But you should run the map function on `props.pokemons`

Comment: @Shuvo Now I get this error message: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: As stated you were mapping props rather than pokemons, also you need to check if undefined/null before doing map as initially it will be undefined as the API call is not immediate. I would recommend you to use "useEffect" in child component to fetch and making sure the list is not undefined/null at any state before mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a summary of my answer

- it is best to fetch some initial data in parent and then make further requests in child
  component if necessary to save network usage
- use the `useEffect` hook to fetch the results before rendering the elements
- What you are missing is that you are not using props in pokemon and you should put the get call inside useEffect hook in `App` component because the child component is rendering before the props is passed to it and this is the reason you are getting `undefined` error

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you very much! So it re-renders my page when the fetch is finished? Does it mean I should set some initial Loading page on every component? Can I check in other components if the data is not null? I know one way: {props.pokemons && PokeList> but it doesn't seem to work for me in this hook setup

Comment: check if the props are there before the return statement in child component like this

Comment: props.pokemon?<yourdata/>:<Loading Screen/>